# angular rendering not working after i use afterRender callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the current code that i am using

```
App.directive('afterRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var def = {
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(scope.$eval(attrs.afterRender), 0);
        }
    };
    return def;
}]);
```

and i call it like

```
after-render="disableFullPage"
```

Now the problem that i am facing with the current code is that disableFullPage function is being called fine. But angular is not rendering any data. So if i put

```
{{message}}
```

that is not being rendered. Also if i remove the after-render, the rendering works fine. Can someone please help me out with what i am doing wrong, also if possible please edit the code above and provide a brief description for my better understanding as i am relatively new to angular.

Comment: Any particular reason why you set `terminial: true`? That is going to disable further evaluation of directives/expressions.

Comment: @Josh i am a newbee here. and the code is not mine. It is just extensive googling around. Let me try with false flag and see if that works :)

Comment: @Josh that works. Add an answer so i can mark it right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two things going on here.

**First**, you are setting `terminal: true` which is going to prevent further interpretation of directives and expressions.

[According to the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-terminal-):

> If set to true then the current priority will be the last set of
>   directives which will execute (any directives at the current priority
>   will still execute as the order of execution on same priority is
>   undefined). **Note that expressions and other directives used in the**
>   **directive's template will also be excluded from execution.**

**Second**, `$parse` is going to evaluate whatever expression you give it in the context of the current scope. It's like you had just written a line of javascript.

In your example above, `after-render="disableFullPage"`, assuming `disableFullPage` is a function, then nothing is going to happen. You need to add the parenthesis like you were calling the function normally:

`after-render="disableFullPage()"`